# Windows Phone 8 mp3 playlist playing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Looking at [Windows Phone 8 mp3 playing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146695/windows-phone-8-mp3-playing-problems), how can I implement a different playlist for multiple buttons? I am looking to have different buttons play different playlists, not just different tracks, and since we cant communicate with the agent, what can I do? Thanks for any help!

By the way the code I have is based from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx if that makes it easier to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can [communicate with the agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202944(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_CommunicationBetweenForegroundApplicationandBackgroundAgent) via IsolatedStorage or with AudioTrack's Tag (in BAP).
First you will need to run it with [one playlist managed from UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946512/how-to-select-a-song-from-playlist-in-background-audio-player). Then when you have that, there is no difference in working if you have one list or more - you just change the audiotrack. You decide how each button responses - your 'play one' can load track from list one, 'play two' loads from second etc..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Romasz, I am already using IsolatedStorage., per the article in my original post. Please see: 
 using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
                string[] files = new string[] { "Track1.mp3", ...};
The problem is that the "AudioPlayer.cs" file contains all the data for the playlist and tracks, and I cannot figure out how to use the same variables in my xaml pages to add logic for different playlists. Could you please give an example? Thank you!

Comment: You can't use the same variables. You need to save your choice on IsolatedStorage and then OnUserAction in Audioplayer load that choice from IsolatedStorge. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you please give an example of how to save which button is pressed on IsolatedStorage?

Comment: You can use for example IsolatedStorageSettings for that. In main UI when you press button you change (or add) key in IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["BtnClicked"]; invoke BAP.Stop(). and BAP.Play(). Then OnUserAction Play you load that button (string)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["BtnClicked"]; and do what you want. And remember to IolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();

Comment: Thanks again. When I click one of the buttons, Im having a new page load, and that is when I need to load a new playlist. I added the following in one of the xamls: IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["BtnClicked"]= "Clicked"; 
           

                BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
         
                BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Stop();
But I am having trouble loading the button. I should load it in "OnUserAction" in "AudioPlayer.cs" correct?

Comment: First you should Stop previous if it's playing, then Play. You can put whatever you want in OnUserAction  in AudioPlayer (even different functionality). Try to debug and see how program work, toggle breakpoint at OnUserAction and step over. Here is also a good blog (3 parts): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpukcoe/archive/2012/02/09/background-audio-in-windows-phone-7-5-part-1.aspx

Comment: I have the following in my "OnNavigateTo" in the xaml.cs: 
  IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["BtnClicked"]= "Clicked";

            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
            BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Stop();    
            BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
          
So is the below what should go in my AudioPlayer.cs?
   if ((string)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["BtnClicked"] == "Clicked")
                    {
'code to play a specific playlist'
                    }
Thank you!

Comment: There are many ways to do what you want, that example you mentioned should work, maybe it's not the most efficient but you will learn how to deal with the problem and then can think about someting different. I think now you will handle this yourself. On this site when somebody solves your problem don't forget to mark the green tick besides the answer. Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: Thank you much, Ill try to take it from here.

Comment: When I click on a page and press Play, the correct track is selected, but as soon as I click on another page, the same track is still selected. Basically the process works only the first time, it seems like I need to flush or clear a variable? Any idea?

Comment: After debugging I see that  ((string)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["BtnClicked"] is only being updated in AudioPlayer.cs the first time even though it is getting changed in the all xamls. How can I force the variable to change in AudioPlayer.cs everytime I open a page?

Comment: @richardchaaya then chcek how many Times you save it. Sorry, but I don't kave so much time to answer your questions. First try to search for answer on this site - most of your questions and doubts is well explained in many posts. Don't give up, learn and keep coding.